# Merge (add and update) rows in batches

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, .net-core, merge

I have huge csv files that I use for generating table information.
First I add all the data to temp table, when I use that data for merge script. Here are my scripts:

```
 public static string GetTempTableScript()
        {
            return $@" 
            IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.##tempImport', 'U') IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
            DROP TABLE ##tempImport;
            END
    
              CREATE TABLE ##tempImport (YearMonthDay datetime NULL,
                Spend decimal (19, 5) NULL, UserId nvarchar(50) NULL, Product nvarchar(255) NULL, GrossMargin decimal (19, 5) NULL);";
        }
        
        public static string GetMergeScript()
        {
            return $@"MERGE
                INTO dbo.TransactionsData AS target
                USING ##tempImport AS source
                ON (source.UserId = target.UserId AND source.ClientId = target.ClientId)
                WHEN MATCHED
                THEN UPDATE SET target.YearMonthDay = source.YearMonthDay, target.Spend = source.Spend,
                target.UserId = source.UserId, target.Product = source.Product,
                target.GrossMargin = source.GrossMargin
                --When no records are matched, insert the incoming records from source table to target table
                WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                    INSERT (YearMonthDay, Spend, UserId, Product, GrossMargin)
                        VALUES (source.YearMonthDay, source.Spend, source.UserId, source.Product, source.GrossMargin);
               ";
        }
```

this is how c# code looks like (temp table is created in batches, while merge is being done all at once):

```
 public async Task BulkImportWithoutDuplicates(IDataReader reader, string temptableScript, string mergeScript, string tableName)
        {
            var sqlCOnn = new SqlConnection(_configurationSettings.ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection);

            var conString = _configurationSettings.ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection;

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(sqlCOnn.ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("", sqlCOnn))
                {
                    sqlCOnn.Open();

                    //Creating temp table on database
                    command.CommandTimeout = 0;
                    command.CommandText = temptableScript;
                    await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    //Bulk insert into temp table
                    using (SqlBulkCopy b = new SqlBulkCopy(conString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock))
                    {
                        b.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
                        b.BatchSize = BATCH_SIZE;
                        b.DestinationTableName = tableName;
                        b.EnableStreaming = true;
                        await b.WriteToServerAsync(reader);
                        b.Close();
                    }
   
                    // Updating destination table
                    command.CommandText = mergeScript;
                    var rows = await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

the problem is that if there's lots of data (e.g. over couple millions) it works very slow and locks the table. That's why I would like to insert/update in batches, but I am not sure how that should work and if it's possible to do that in merge script or should I do something else to optimize inserting/updating rows?

Comment: Don't use MERGE for bulk operations. For one thing, it's *not* an atomic operation and requires an explicit transaction. It's better to use separate UPDATE and INSERT operation by joining the source and target tables.  As for updating 1M rows, it will probably lock the table no matter what, as this is a significant percentage of the overall rows. Unless you have 1Bn rows.

Comment: If you want to modify the entire table, a viable solution is to insert the new data in a new staging table with the same schema as the target table and switch partitions between the two tables. The INSERT operation will be fast, won't take any exclusive locks on the target table, and the final swap operation is instantaneous as it's just a metadata operation

Comment: Check [Fast fact table loading with partition switching](https://sqlsunday.com/2014/08/24/reloading-fact-tables-with-zero-downtime/) and [Keeping Fact Tables Online while Loading via Partition Switching](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/keeping-fact-tables-online-while-loading-via-partition-switching)

Comment: I want to modify not the entire table, the data that comes is for one client @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: How much data is that? How often is that operation - and why would you have to *update* millions of rows each time? Even so, you can partition the table by customer (something available in all supported versions and editions of SQL Server) and insert, swap partitions

Comment: After all, it seems like you're replacing, not updating the data for one client.

Comment: I'm updating if it matches condition and inserting if not matches. In csv files comes clients transaction data. In perfect world each excel file should contain differente data without duplicates. But user might want to fix some incorecct data with dfferent file, so we have option overwrite (delete all client's data and then insert) or add and update this is where I use these scripts. @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: That's why the specifics matter. Different problems require different techniques. If you have to replace all a customer's data, you can use partition switching. If you have to update just a subset of rows, you can use UPDATE. If you have to update a *lot* of rows, copying the data to a staging table and working there won't stop productions. DELETE and re-INSERT is faster than UPDATE but means the data will be inconsistent for a while. Those are all *different* problems.

Comment: BTW I have the same problem**s** - handling million of air ticket transactions. I use all those techniques. *For small data* I even used `MERGE` when I felt lazy - until I found it throws bogus `duplicate key` errors if you SET the PK columns in `UPDATE`. Something that shouldn't happen because those were used to join after all! This happens even with explicit transactions. Interesting MERGE bug. Not the only one

Comment: BTW I see you set `UserID` in the `UPDATE` clause, which means you could encounter the same bug

Comment: My experience pretty exactly matches @PanagiotisKanavos.  I used MERGE until I encountered issues.  Then I used it when lazy to "make these rows look like those rows" situations. Now I never use it ever.  The transactional issues are mostly solved by setting Xact_abort on (NEVER use MERGE without that) but still it's nearly always slower (check the Docs. it says it clearly) and there are other issues too

Comment: The temp table is declared with global scope (##) purely so that it can be referenced by the MERGE statement?

Comment: This would be better converted to a stored procedure and split into separate statements.  Is that OK?